# app is crash when html content is coming how to handle in android?

Tags: android, html, json

i am register using email and password if email and domain is exit it is successfull work
but if a@a.com like pass in email than it give me back html and my app is crash so how to handle this content

```
public String webregister(String url, String u, String p) 
    {

        // Create a new httpclient and send post header
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // returns true if username and password is valid
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json = null;
        InputStream is;

        try 
        {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", u));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", p));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


            // getting the response
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;

    }
```

> ErrorLogcat

```
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register Url(1474): ---->http://interntest.monitorwerbung.at/studio/webservices/register
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): ----><!doctype html>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="de" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="de" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="de" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <head>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   <title>monitorwerbung - Errors</title>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <link href="/studio/backend.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/studio/backend.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" />
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/studio/css/reset.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/studio/css/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/studio/css/default.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/studio/css/jquery.minicolors.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/modernizr.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/jquery.minicolors.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/studio/js/global.js"></script></head>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <body>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <div id="LiveSearchResult"></div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <div class="wrapper">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       <div class="sidebar">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           <div id="logo">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               <img src="/studio/img/logo.png" alt="Peakmedia" />          </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           <div class="profile-info">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               Hallo <a href="/studio/managers/profile"></a>! |
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               <a href="/studio/managers/logout">Abmelden</a>              <div>27.06.2014 16:10</div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           <div id="livesearch">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               <input type="text" name="data[Search][livesearch]" id="SearchLivesearch" placeholder="Durchsuchen" />
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):                       
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           <div class="menu">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               <ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <li><a href="/studio/home">Dashboard</a></li>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):               </ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):                
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       </ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           </ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):                       </ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <ul>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       </ul>           </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       <div class="content">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):           <h2>An Internal Error Has Occurred.</h2>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): <p class="error">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   <strong>Error: </strong>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   An Internal Error Has Occurred.</p>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):                   </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       <div class="clear"></div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):   </div>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474):       <script type="text/javascript">
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): //<![CDATA[
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): $(document).ready(function () {$("#SearchLivesearch").bind("keyup", function (event) {if ($("#SearchLivesearch").val().length > 2) {$.ajax({async:true, data:$("#SearchLivesearch").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#LiveSearchResult").html(data);$("#LiveSearchResult").show()}, type:"post", url:"/studio/admin/search/livesearch"});return false;} else {$("#LiveSearchResult").hide();}});});
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): //]]>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): </script></body>
06-27 19:40:23.585: E/Register(1474): </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solutions of my own question i tried something and it is work for me

```
            boolean containsHTML=false;

            Pattern htmlPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\<[^>]+>.*", Pattern.DOTALL);

            containsHTML=htmlPattern.matcher(data).matches();
            if(containsHTML)
            {   

                \\ not parsing or set message : invalid data

            }
            else
            {
                 \\ do jsonparsing here
            }
```